# How to use secret in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a YAML file that declares the secrets as such:

```yaml
# api version, kind, etc declared
data: 
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dGhpc2lzYXRlc3R0aGluZy4K
   MYSQL_HOST: bXlzcWwtc2VydmljZQo=
```

and this is for secrets declared in yaml file like this:

```yaml
# api version, kind, etc declared
- name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
           valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: mysecret
               key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

- name: MYSQL_HOST
           valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: mysecret
               key: MYSQL_HOST
```

I want to be able to access this from a Python file, where they were accessed like this before they were turned to secrets:

```py
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'HOST': os.environ.get('MYSQL_HOST'),
       'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'),
   }
}
```

I've tried this:

```py
host = ""
password = ""

def decode() {
    config.load_kube_config()
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    host = v1.read_namespaced_secret("MYSQL_HOST", "default")
    password = v1.read_namespaced_secret("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD", "default")
    host = base64.b64decode(host.strip().split()[1].translate(None, '}\''))
    password = base64.b64decode(password.strip().split()[1].translate(None, '}\''))
}
```

and pass the variables like such:

```py
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'HOST': host,
       'PASSWORD': password,
   }
}
```

but this doesn't work. How would I do this?

Comment: Before going into python, if you enter in the container and execute "env" do you see the environment variables and its content?

Comment: @Jxadro how would I do this?

Comment: Into your namespace, "kubectl get pods", take note of you pod id, kubectl exec -ti <your pod id> -- /bin/bash

Comment: Then just execute "env"

Comment: @Jxadro it says MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD' in secret 'mysecret'>  Optional: false
      MYSQL_HOST:           <set to the key 'MYSQL_HOST' in secret 'mysecret'>  Optional: false

Comment: I'd expect your original code would work fine: Kubernetes still sets the environment variables, just their content comes from a different source.  Do you get an error or failure when you try it?

Comment: The varialbes are there (it worth you update the question with this information).

Comment: Are you sure there are no typos? I would test again with ConfigMap and the same Image. Also execute the env to double check